# python set to take the difference of name values between two files

Tags: python-3.x, set

While using python `set()` i found it really faster than a conventional loop over a list records, i have tried to pull the data with sets() for the unique records between the files and really found it great, However, i'm just looking if there is way where i can compare and get the names which are in  `file_noi1` but not in `file_noi2` using set.

```
dataList1 = []
dataList2 = []

with open('file_noi1', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split()
    for line in lines:
        dataList1.append(line)


with open('file_noi2', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split()
    for line in lines:
        dataList2.append(line)

dataset1 = set(dataList1)
dataset2 = set(dataList2)
records = list(dataset1.intersection(dataset2))
#print(records)
for (i, item) in enumerate(records):
        #print("Seq Number #%d is %s" % (i, str(item)))
        print(str(item))
```

above script works perfectly for unique records.

Names are as bleow in the files

file_noi1

```
narni
mariya
tory
james
karin
steve
```

file_noi2

```
narni
mariya
tory
james
```

Expected result:

```
karin
steve
```

Comment: How does the data look? What do you mean `names`? Show us the records. Better: show expected input and output.

Comment: Does `ile_noi1 - ile_noi2` not work?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you are correct ,  i believe `dataset1.difference(dataset2)` should  do the Job,  i'm trying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's address your loading code. You don't need to construct a list for each file: you can add elements directly to a set. Sets accept any reasonable iterable as input to their constructor. Files are iterable over their lines, so you can truncate your initialization to four lines:

```
with open('file_noi1', 'r') as f:
    dataset1 = set(f)
with open('file_noi2', 'r') as f:
    dataset2 = set(f)
```

From your example, you are looking either for [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference), which is implemented through the `-` operator, or [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference), implemented through the `^` operator. Since `dataset2` is strictly a subset of `dataset1`, both of the following will give the desired result:

```
dataset1 - dataset2
```

AND

```
dataset1 ^ dataset2
```

The difference (no pun intended) is that the latter operation will contain elements from either set which aren't in the other, and therefore commutes.

Keep in mind that sets aren't ordered, so enumerating over a set may not be all that useful unless you sort it first:

```
for i, e in enumerate(sorted(dataset1 ^ dataset2)):
    ...
```

Comment: While using the given solution with for loop throws below error.

`    for i, e in sorted(dataset1 ^ dataset2):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
`

Comment: @pygo. I forgot to enumerate. Fixed now.

Comment: thnx however , while enumerating it placed a newline after each record on the print and i see set() do ot take `strip`.  `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: Why are you attempting to strip anything here?

Comment: My bad , got it , you made my day and a complete learning for the day -)  , you are right i am doing wrong i should do it here `print(str(item).strip())`.

Comment: i'm compiling your answer as a better one to mark it.  Thnx again for helping.

Answer (score 2):

while intersection gives you the intersection between two sets, the difference gives the difference between two sets. But do  know that A - B and B - A in the set isn't the same.

So here's a little solution which will help you.

```
fileno_1 = set(["narni","mariya","tory","james","karin","steve"])
fileno_2 = set(["narni","mariya","tory","james"])
output = list(fileno_1.difference(fileno_2))
print(output)
# prints ['steve', 'karin']
```

this should help you.

Comment: yes i later realised when MadPhysicist given the hint.